# Cannot find module "path to feature module" when lazy loading

Tags: angular, ionic3, lazy-loading

### Ionic Lazy Loading Error

I'm encountering the following stacktrace error when I'm trying to configure Lazy Loading:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find module 'pages/home/home.module'.
Error: Cannot find module 'pages/home/home.module'.
    at http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:10:9
    at t.invoke (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:14976)
    at Object.onInvoke (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:5134:33)
    at t.invoke (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:14916)
    at r.run (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:10143)
    at http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:20242
    at t.invokeTask (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:15660)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:5125:33)
    at t.invokeTask (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:15581)
    at r.runTask (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:10834)
    at c (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:19752)
    at c (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:19461)
    at http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:20233
    at t.invokeTask (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:15660)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:5125:33)
    at t.invokeTask (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:15581)
    at r.runTask (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:10834)
    at o (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:7894)
```

#### Configuration

```
Ionic Framework: 3.9.2
Ionic App Scripts: 3.2.1
Angular Core: 5.2.11
Angular Compiler CLI: 5.2.11
Node: 10.12.0
OS Platform: macOS
Navigator Platform: MacIntel
User Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36
```

#### Code Snippets

Here are some of the files:

[app-routing.module.ts](https://github.com/darrensapalo/ionic-lazy-loading-error/blob/master/src/app/app-routing.module.ts)

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'home', loadChildren: "pages/home/home.module#HomePageModule" },
    { path: 'form', loadChildren: "pages/form/form.module#FormPageModule" },
    { path: '',  redirectTo: '/home',  pathMatch: 'full' }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
        enableTracing: true
    }) ],
    exports: [ RouterModule ]
})

export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

I've tried variations of the values for `loadChildren`, such as:

`pages/home/home.module#HomePageModule`

`./home/home.module#HomePageModule`

`../pages/home/home.module#HomePageModule`

#### Things to note

- On my `app/app.module.ts`, I already don't import the modules to be lazy-loaded.
- On my `app/app.component.ts`, I use a string reference to my `HomePage` module.
- On my `app/app-routing.module.ts`, The routes use `loadChildren` that references the filepath to my modules.
- App module uses `RouterModule.forRoot` while Feature modules in the `pages` folder use `RouterModule.forChild`.

Not sure what else to do here, I followed the instructions for lazy-loading on the ionic documentation and I read through Angular documentation for lazy-loading.

## Questions

1. How do I fix the "cannot find module" error? I know the files are there but Ionic/Angular isn't able to find where the module files are.
2. Do I actually need to have external dependencies like [angular-router-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-router-loader) to enable angular to load modules from string-based file path references?

## Github Repository

To reproduce the bug, please check out the repository below:

https://github.com/darrensapalo/ionic-lazy-loading-error

Comment: `Pages` directory should be in `app` folder because otherwise you need to set path for the same, by default Angular will look for Pages in App folder

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've moved my `pages` folder inside the `app` folder, but it still shows the same problem. I've restarted it with `ionic serve` already but it still says the same thing.

Comment: can you reproduce the same error on stackblitz?

Comment: I'll try to now.

Comment: Turns out that stackblitz doesn't allow these types of projects on their system. https://stackblitz.com/github/darrensapalo/ionic-lazy-loading-error